# Google indexing fewer images after switching to CDN

Tags: images, search-engine-indexing, cdn, google-image-search

After switching to a CDN I noticed that my indexed image count went down. I have close to 1000 images on the site with correct tags, alt tags, and all of that. Only 50 are actually being indexed in the organic search.

It's a WordPress site with Yoast SEO plugin, using Maxcdn as my CDN.

Answer (score 4):

Moving images to a CDN is similar to migrating the URLs of other content.

- Use a subdomain of your main domain (images.example.com), don't use the CDN domain name (893.mebes.bigbadcdnhost.tld)
- Use 301 permanent redirect (`www.example.com/images/foo.jpg` to `images.example.com/images/foo.jpg`)
- Update your site so that you refer to the images at their new URLs everywhere on your site.
- Ensure that your images are crawlable on the CDN (not blocked by `robots.txt`)

I helped move images to a CDN a few years ago.  With those rules in place, we didn't lose any image search rankings.

Comment: +1 this. @user32160 Also since your using Maxcdn, they have a robots.txt feature to block content. In your case you do not want that enabled.

Comment: Good point, Anthony, I've added that to my answer.